# Repair broken TFS WorkItem links during TFS-to-DevOps migration

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-migration-tools

I'm using the [Azure DevOps Migration Tools](https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/) software to migrate our on-site TFS projects to DevOps. We have many projects that contain circular links between project Work Items.

For example,

- `ProjectA.WorkItem#1` related to `ProjectB.WorkItem#2`
- `ProjectB.WorkItem#3` related to `ProjectA.WorkItem#4`

Assuming I migrate ProjectA first, and then ProjectB second, the link between `#1` and `#2` will be invalid, but the link between `#3` and `#4` will be intact.

I've reviewed the documentation as best as I can, but couldn't seem to find a "Repair broken links" option. If I re-run the migration tool again, it doesn't find any changes to the work items so it skips them.

Is there any way to repair the link for `#1 -> #2` once they both exist on the DevOps server?

Comment: Please check whether [this question](https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools/issues/375) could help you.

Comment: @JaneMa-MSFT The initial question sounds like it could satisfy my needs. However, there were no details explaining how it actually would work or how to configure the tool to migrate those links separately. Then the ticket digresses into basic ticket migration discussions.

Comment: Please create an issue on https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools/issues so we can have a discussion

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to run the links separately, but that's an interesting conundrum.

Since we added support for cross-team-project linking it is creating links to the pre-existing Work Items in the same collection. This would not happen if you were moving collection but within the same collection.

> When ProjectA.WorkItem#1 is processed since the target work item
> exists (ProjectB.WorkItem#2) it will go ahead and create that valid
> link. Which is then invalid when ProjectB is migrated
>
> When ProjectB.WorkItem#3 is processed since ProjectA.WorkItem#4 has
> already been migrated it links correctly to the new item.

Can you tell me in what way the link created previously is invalid? Does it persist when ProjectB is deleted?

Comment: I realized that I have some other issues causing problems with my work item migrations, so it's possible those are causing issues. Once I've worked out all of the problems I will come back with more information.